# How to set up Angular project to be able to use mixins?

Tags: css, angular, scss-mixins

I have an Angular 16 project with this scss files:

**styles.scss**

```
@import url(./assets/scss/mixins.scss);
@import url(./assets/scss/elements.scss);
```

**assets/scss/mixins.scss**

```
@mixin no-text-selection {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

**assets/scss/elements.scss**

```
@import './mixins.scss';

input[type='checkbox'] {
  cursor: pointer;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;

  + label {
    cursor: pointer;
    @include no-text-selection;
  }
}
```

Looks like it should be working, but Edge/Chrome/Firefox gives an "Unknown property name":

[image: Edge]

The project was initially set to use css files, so perhaps there's something missing?
I'm simply doing `ng serve` to run the web-app.

Comment: [`@import`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import/) is used at the top-level of your scss stack. Then other files later in the stack can use declarations from it. It will be removed in the future. [`@use`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use/) on the other hand provides a more granular way of defining dependencies between stylesheets, where dependencies in a file are specified within the file itself. [Here's](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use/#loading-members) an example.

Comment: Is that the rendered CSS in the image? Obviously it wasn't compiled, if so.

Comment: I had two issues: SCSS files were located in assets folder and they were not referenced in the angular.json file. Now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

We need to:

1. Not add style files in assets folder *(duh)*.

Those files will be copied as is and we don't want that.

2. Reference separate style files in `angular.json`:

```json
"build": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
  "options": {
    "outputPath": "dist/angularapp",
    "index": "src/index.html",
    "main": "src/main.ts",
    "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
    "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
    "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
    "assets": [
      "src/favicon.ico",
      "src/assets"
    ],
    "styles": [ /* Here! */
      "src/styles.scss",
      "src/styles/mixins.scss",
      "src/styles/global.scss",
      "src/styles/elements.scss",
      "src/styles/icons.scss",
      "src/styles/layout.scss",
    ],
    "scripts": []
  },
```

3. Import mixins at the top of the file:

```
@import './mixins.scss';

...

input[type='checkbox'] {
  cursor: pointer;

  + label {
    @include no-text-selection;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

`@use` doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

the initial setup to use css, needs a specific way to be migrated using scss, read this https://medium.com/motf-creations/migrate-from-css-to-scss-stylesheets-for-existing-angular-application-d61f8061f5b7 and check if everything is as described in the article! cheers!

Comment: Read what? Include the relevant parts of the article here